# Used vs Max vs Size -Jvisualvm?

Tags: java, performance, memory, heap-memory, jvisualvm

In jvisual vm i see three attributes under Monitor>Heap, i see  3 attributes depicting memory details all with differnt figures

1. Size : ?
2. Used  :- I believe this is the actual memory used
3. Max :- I believe this is the max heap size allocated to java process (specified  with Xmx)

I am not sure what size actually depicts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three attributes can be defined as next:

1. **Size:** The actual total reserved heap size
2. **Used:** The actual used heap size.
3. **Max:** The max size of the Java heap (young generation + tenured generation)

Indeed when you launch your JVM, the initial heap size (can be defined with `-Xms`) will be the initial **total reserved heap size**, then according to how your application behaves, it could need to increase **the total reserved size** until it reaches the max size and if it is still not enough you could get OOME.

Comment: @Niolas Filotto Can we connect at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/126453/java-discussion?tab=access&highlight=1997376 ?

Answer (score 1):

Size depicts the heap block size assigned to java process. Try with -Xms  512m or 1024m then your size to start with will be 512m but used memory may be much lower. As soon as used memory grows , heap resizing occurs proactively so that memory can be allocated to live objects.

Its  like you have Gas tank of 30 litre max capacity . But you know for now you may just need 20 litres for the trip but actually used in trip is 5 litres

Answer (score 1):

**Heap size** is actual size of heap your running application has.
**Used heap** is used portion of heap size.
**Max heap size** is the maximum value the application's heap size can have (can be defined by the arg [option -Xmx](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)).
When monitor memory usage of a java application, you see that **heap size** may vary during running of the application. It can not be greater than **max heap size**. For a sample profiling (monitoring of an application), see below image:
[image: heap snapshot]

Comment: this is very confusing, and rather wrong too. how can you make a difference between _is actual size of heap your running application has_ and _is used portion of heap size_ - you make no sense.